# Save to my media library boolean

Tags: 8, media

When you add media inside the Ckeditor. The media upload dialog has this checkbox option. Its a field inside the Image/Document Bundle. What does this option do? When uploading images/documents using the ckeditor or using a reference field. If I check this or not, the image is always added and listed in the Media library. Is it safe to hide this field from Editors? It says save to 'MY' media library, so is there a user media library that is different than the media view located at /admin/content/media/. I went to manage fields in both Image and Documents and made sure this field is not on by default. This is related to https://www.drupal.org/node/2757473

Comment: Where is this option?

Comment: Sorry for not adding more detail. In the Drupal Lightning repo. When you add media inside the Ckeditor. The media upload dialog has this checkbox option. Its a field inside the Image Bundle. I believe on a plain Drupal 8 site. You have to install the Media modules to get this feature.